# Git - push does not update files in the repository

Tags: git

I have cloned Git repository from C:/temp/NetBeansProjects to C:/temp1/NetBeansProjects. I have changed the content of one file, "Version.java", on temp1, then staged it and committed it. Then I pushed it to the repository in temp using

```
git push origin master
```

I got messages that the push is successful and git status gives me message "Everything up-to-date". However, when I go to temp to check the content of the file "Version.java" I cannot see any changes, the file has not been updated, even date stamp is old.

I am on Windows 7 Professional.

Am I missing any steps in this whole procedure?

Comment: You're sure origin is set to temp?

Comment: Do `git log` in both repos and see whether they are at the same commit.

Comment: I have checked git log, both have the same commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you have pushed into non-bare repository. In this case, repository is changed, but working copy files are not updated. Please read about bare and non-bare repositories.

You could see the difference using `git status` in the `temp`.

Do `git checkout .` in the `temp` to update working copy files from the repository.

Comment: Before the push I made the repository temp bare with "git config --bool core.bare true". After this, the push still did not changed the file on temp. When I run "git checkout ." on temp I am getting a message "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree".

Comment: @Nash How do you check changes in Version.java if it is bare repository? Bare repositories do not have working files.

Comment: You are right. I clarified what is bare and non-bare repository. Now I made temp to be pure bare repository without working tree. Deleted all the files too. Now, the clone and updates work fine. Thanks for your answers and questions.